# Is there a way in R to merge two variables (or columns) despite both containing missing values?

Tags: r

So, my data is structured roughly as follows:

| Groups | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 3.5 | NA | NA |
| Second | NA | 4.3 | NA |
| Third | NA | NA | 5.2 |

To make life easier, I would like a way to create a new column "AB" where I get
|AB   |
|---- |
|3.5  |
|4.3  |
|NA   |

I tried using the pivot.longer function, but this gives me an error message "Error in `build_longer_spec()`:
! Selections can't have missing values."

Could anyone help with this? Appreciate it!

Comment: Re your comment on Akrun's answer, in df1$AB it should be AB. The df1$ is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `coalesce` which selects the first non-NA element from each row of the columns passed

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(AB = coalesce(A, B))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! If I type that in I get "Error: unexpected '=' in:
"df1 <- data2 %>%
  mutate(data2$AB ="

Comment: @Woelfchen99 I don't understand why you change the code to `data2$` within mutate.   If you check my code, I used only `mutate(AB = ..`, With tidyverse, you don't need to data2$ or data2[[.  there is data binding